# measuring response time through packets?

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, winpcap

good day!
im developing an app in c++ and winpcap that will list all the URL accessed in the browser with its corresponding response time..
currently, i can now track or monitor all accessed url through capturing and analyzing packets..
is there any way of measuring the response time of a web page to load, from the request made to the server's response?..
any easy way?

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to keep track of the individual TCP connections between the browser and the server - 
that's just keeping track of the source/destination IP and port numbes in the packets you capture.

Then you'll have to parse the HTTP in the captured packets and correlate HTTP requests with its response and take the time difference(which you'll get from the timestamps from pcap).

This is non-trivial in the cases the HTTP request/responses spans several packets, and certainly non-trivial if you also want to account for lost packets and retransmission.